# neo (near-earth-object) and near-earth-asteroid tags, do we need both?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [neo](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo) tag has 21 questions and its excerpt says:

> Questions about Near-Earth Objects or NEO for short, a term describing meteoroids, asteroids, comets, man-made spacecraft, space observatories, and space debris whose orbit brings them into proximity with Earth.

The [near-earth-asteroid](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-earth-asteroid) tag has 29 questions and no excerpt.

There are [only three question that have both tags](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo+near-earth-asteroid) (all mine).

**Question:** Is this okay? Are they exclusive distinctions? Should they be merged?

**note:** I've just asked in Astronomy SE: [Is there a distinction between NEO's and near-earth-asteroids? Is there a difference?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35142/7982) Hopefully we can gain some perspective from answers there. I noticed that [Astronomy SE has only near-earth-object](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-earth-object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near-Earth asteroids are a perfect subset of Near-Earth objects, which means that the tag is distinct, though overlapping. Since [near-earth-asteroid](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-earth-asteroid) has more questions than [neo](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo), I think it makes sense to maintain as a separate tag, but it could use a tag excerpt as you've pointed out.

Comment: my concern is that out of 47 questions there are only three that have both tags. I haven't read through them yet, but if someone is looking for questions about near-earth-objects with the `neo` tag (which should be a catch-all), they're going to miss the 26 questions lacking that tag, but instead were tagged `near-earth-asteroid`. I don't see how this situation is good.

Comment: @uhoh That can be remedied by referring to [tag:near-earth-asteroids] in the excerpt or wiki for [tag:neo] (depending on whether the excerpt has enough space).

Comment: That way users know there's another tag to search.

Comment: @uhoh I added "See also: [near-earth-asteroid]" to the [tag:neo] excerpt and "See also: [neo]" to the [tag:near-earth-asteroid] excerpt. I also created the synonym [tag:near-earth-object] for [tag:neo].