# Reverse the [neo] and [near-earth-object] synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Related to [this question](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/neo-near-earth-object-and-near-earth-asteroid-tags-do-we-need-both)

Right now we have [near-earth-asteroid](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-earth-asteroid) and [neo](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo), which has [near-earth-object] as a synonym. This is potentially confusing to users, and if there's any other NEO acronyms out there, people might misuse the tag.

I would like to suggest we reverse the synonym and make [near-earth-object] the tag, which keeps with existing nomenclature.

Comment: I've implemented the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with this change, and I've now implemented it!

Comment: Will the desired result be the single [near-earth-object] tag on all 47 questions?

Comment: @uhoh No, this would just be flipping neo and near-earth-objects.

Comment: I see, since the *asteroids* subset [is probably 99% the size](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/35158/7982) of the catch-all *objects* category I still think that one tag (what Astronomy has) will be in practice [better than](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1459/12102) two for search and migration reasons, unless there are other objects besides asteroids and comets that I don't know about.

Comment: @uhoh There are three questions in near-earth-object that are not about asteroids. Though not much, I think that is just enough to justify maintaining two tags.

Comment: If my arithmetic is correct (it's late here) I think that means that there are about 15 questions about near-earth-asteroids that don't have a near-earth-asteroid tag. The status quo seems sub-optimal.

Comment: @uhoh We maintain separate superset/subset tags all the time. I wish the system had a more standard way of linking tags with that relationship, but I think it makes sense to keep them separate, even if it's mostly redundant. If you already have four tags and you want to add one more, it's nice to have a more specific tag to add.

Comment: Sub/super tagging as a concept is fine with me, 1) would me slowly adding the near-earth-asteroids tag to all of the near-earth-asteroids questions that don't have it be okay then? 2) should they all keep their near-earth-object tag as well?

Comment: @uhoh Any question that can support both tags (i.e. it's about asteroids and doesn't already have four/five tags) can (and probably should) have both, yes.

Comment: I once got a superset tag removed: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453460/mass-distributions-within-two-bodies-such-that-the-orbit-is-no-longer-keplerian#comment1022159_453460

Comment: @uhoh Yeah, that's "general guidance", but I'm not as strict about that as they are on Physics. There's a good reason to allow using both: making sure people monitoring a certain tag see your question and making sure those answering get credit toward that tag (this allows them to build up toward their tag badges, which incentivizes answering).

Comment: @uhoh Also, tag badges are a better indicator of someone's knowledge in a certain area if they can include as many of their relevant answers as possible.

Comment: Okay I see. I know badges exist and are important to some people (gamification isn't evil), but I'm primarily concerned with tags as an indexing method; if I want to quickly get all the questions and answers about say near-earth-asteroids, then I want the near-earth-asteroid to do that. Okay thanks